# Combine java code and dependencies into one jar (executable jar) using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, executable-jar

I'm trying to compile my src into one jar file with Netbeans. I currently compile via the right click Build with Dependecies. Here is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ca.osmcanada</groupId>
    <artifactId>OSVUploadr</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-ALPHA</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ca.osmcanada.osvuploadr.JFMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ca.osmcanada.osvuploadr.JFMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I execute the output jar file it can't find the com.github.scribejava and com.drewnoakes libraries. Also if I don't use the maven-jar-plugin the main class doesnt get added to the meta-inf/manifest.mf. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are using maven version 3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put the execution tag outside configuration tag for maven-assembly-plugin, like below:

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>ca.osmcanada.osvuploadr.JFMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> 
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>`